# CouchDB, MapReduce: query a time slice

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

For a monitoring an application with CouchDB I need to sum up a field of my data (for example the time needed to execute a method that has been logged).

That's no problem for me with map-reduce, but I need to sum up only the data recorded in a special time slice.

Example records:

```
{_id: 1, methodID:1, recorded: 100, timeneeded: 10}, 
{_id: 2, methodID:1, recorded: 200, timeneeded: 11}, 
{_id: 3, methodID:2, recorded: 200, timeneeded: 2}, 
{_id: 4, methodID:1, recorded: 300, timeneeded: 6}, 
{_id: 5, methodID:2, recorded: 310, timeneeded: 3}, 
{_id: 6, methodID:1, recorded: 400, timeneeded: 9}
```

Now I would like to get just the sum of `timeneeded` of all records that have been `recorded` in the range of 200 to 350 and grouped by `methodID`. (That would be 17 for `methodID:1` and 5 for `methodID:2`.)

How can I do that?

---

I now tried it with a list function that's using WickedGrey's idea. See my functions here:

map function:

```
function(doc) {  
  emit([ doc.recorded], {methodID:doc.methodID, timeneeded:doc.timeneeded}); 
}
```

list function:

```
"function(head, req) {  
  var combined_values = {};
  var row;   
  while (row = getRow()) {  

      if( row.values.methodID in combined_values)     { 
        combined_values[ row.values.methodID] +=row.values.timeneeded; 
      }        
      else {  
        combined_values[ row.values.methodID] = row.values.timeneeded;    
      } 

  } 

  for(var methodID in combined_values){ 
    send( toJSON({method: methodID, timeneeded:combined_values[methodID]}) );
  }   
}"
```

Now I have to problems: 
1. I always get the results as a file and my firefox asks me if I want to download it, instead of viewing it in the browser like when I query a classic view.
2. As I understand the thing, the results are now calculated on the fly, in the list function. I expect this to be not really fast with hundrets of millions of records... Any ideas how to get it faster?

Thank you for your help!
andy

Comment: After your edits, I'm not clear on your scenario. You give example records, then go on to use fields that aren't in those docs.

Comment: @MetaThis I'm sorry for the mistake, the names changed a bit in my application, but to be consistent I edited my post to match to termes used in this thread.

Comment: I fixed the bug in my list function and updated my post.

Comment: Andy, did you get this figured out? I am curious what your solution was.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a map key to filter by one set of criteria, but group by another in CouchDB.  However, you can filter the keys by time range, and group with a reduce function.  Try something like this:

```
function map(doc) {
    emit(doc.recorded, {doc.methodID: doc.timeneeded});
}

function reduce(key, values, rereduce) {
    var combined_values = {};
    for (var i in values) {
        var totals = values[i];
        for (var methodID in totals) {
            if (methodID in combined_values) {
                combined_values[methodID] += totals[methodID];
            }
            else {
                combined_values[methodID] = totals[methodID];
            }
        }
    }
    return combined_values;
}
```

That should allow you to specify a start/end key, and with group_level=0 should get you a value containing the dictionary that you're looking for.

Edit:  Also, this thread might be of interest:

http://couchdb-development.1959287.n2.nabble.com/reduce-limit-error-td2789734.html

It discusses an option to turn off the reduce must shrink message, and further down the list provides other ways of achieving the same goal: using a list function.  That might be a better approach that what I've outlined here.  :(

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (Just to help people reading this, you forgot the return statement in the reduce function and as far as I found out, the {doc.methodID:doc.timeneeded} statement is not possible that way. I do it the following way now: var obj = new Object(); obj[doc.methodID]=doc.timeneeded; and then emit the obj. Thanks again!

Comment: Me again... I now have the problem that couchdb warns me "reduce output must shrink more rapidly". Is there a way to get the result in a simmilar way as I get it with the answer of WickedGrey but letting it shrink rapdily enough? (The output of his suggestion really fits my needs perfectly...). As I understand the problem it's just that his solution gives me one row with every data and couchdb prefers to put the data in different rows...

Comment: Sorry about the reduce errors!  Here's the original thread about the "must shrink" error: http://couchdb-development.1959287.n2.nabble.com/reduce-limit-error-td2789734.html

Comment: Hello WickedGrey; I also found that thread... and I disabled the check but now I have the issue that the view generation needs A LOT more time... It's even taking that much resources, that writes fail during view generation (I let the view generate after about 300 new records)

Answer (score 1):

```
function map(doc) {
  if(doc.methodID && doc.recorded && doc.timeneeded) {
    emit([doc.methodID,doc.recorded], doc.timeneeded);
  }
}

//reduce
_sum
```

Comment: Hi, maybee I'm wrong, but isn't your map function hard coded for a special time slice? Because I need to be able to change the time slice. For example I want the data of the last three days... (And temporary views won't work with about 1 billion rows...)

Comment: I didn't realize that the range given was just an example. If you want to be able to query by the range, then use a composite key and range query. I edited the above to use a key of [doc.methodID,doc.recorded] instead of doc.methodID.

Comment: I also came to this solution. But now I have the issue that if I want to query the data for all methodIDs in a given time slice I need to query your view for every methodID. A single query is fast, but I have to do about at least 2000 of them. That's why I'm looking for a different solution. Sorry that I didn't update my question.

Comment: Then `emit([doc.recorded,doc.methodID], doc.timeneeded);` and reduce to a key of doc.methodID with a sum of the values (doc.timeneeded), and range query with the desired doc.recorded, but all doc.methodIDs.

Comment: Hi, I tried your idea, but now I remember why I didn't use this approach before... If I build a key [doc.recorded,doc.methodID], I have the problem, that almost nothing gets reduced.And therefore I get a really long list of values, one for every time slice my datas have been recorded (about each second). I don't think that it is a good idea to let the client do the "rest" aka. the main part of the work... Do I miss something? Or does anyone have any other ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't demonstrate the code, but the idea would be to reduce to your methodID. That is, the map is timeneeded by a key of [recorded, methodID], but the reduce should reduce timeneeded values by a key of methodID.